# this is a design from the 1960s by Gysin & Sommerville

Tags: prior-art, design-patent, usd675368

this design has been created by Brion Gysin and Ian Sommerville in the 1960s... you did NOT invent neither the contraption, nor (even less) the "ornamental design".

Comment: This is a design patent, not a utility (machine) patent. Simply put, the "look" has been patented.

Comment: @ Ron J. (May 27) you say "the «look» has been patented" - but the fact is that not only the function but also this exact look ("appearance"? "design"?) has been created by Gysin...

Answer (score 1):

The examiner was made aware of at least some of Gysin's work by an IDS (Information Disclosure Statement) filed by the applicant. Here is one page of the 5 page IDS from the image file wrapper at USPTO Public PAIR.

[image]